# Cartan-Hadamard and universal covers

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

The Cartan-Hadamard theorem says that if $M$ is a complete manifold with non-positive sectional curvature, then its universal cover is diffeomorphic to a Euclidean space.

Presumably I've misunderstood something, because this suggests that hyperbolic space has a universal cover that's diffeomorphic to the plane. But surely that can't be the case or else hyperbolic space wouldn't need to be mentioned explicitly in the uniformization theorem.

Where have I gone wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You're confusing "diffeomorphic" and "isometric." Hyperbolic space (say, the open disk, or the upper half-plane) is already diffeomorphic to the plane, by the way.

Comment: Lovely, thank you